# WPF XBAP treeview unable to select child item

Tags: wpf, treeview, xbap

Am using a WPF XBAP application with a TreeView control. The Treeview has a custom ItemContainerStyle and uses Hierarchical data binding. When I minimize the browser running the XBAP and maximize it again and click on an item in the TreeView, the item is not getting selected ie. the SelectedItemChanged event handler is not firing.
Below is the style I'm using for the TreeViewItem:

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0"
                     Opacity="0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Image x:Name="imgExpand" Source="Images/plus.png"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="imgExpand" Value="Images/minus.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsItemExpanded}" />
        <!--<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsEntitySelected}" />-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grd">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorLn" Height="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stroke="White"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerLn" Width="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stroke="White"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <!--<Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" x:Name="imgFlag"/>-->
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"/>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={x:Static converters:TreeViewLineConverter.Instance}}" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="VerLn"
                                Property="Height"
                                Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="VerLn"
                                Property="VerticalAlignment"
                                Value="Top"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">                            
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#71a3ff"/>                            
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>                            
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#71a3ff"/>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>                            
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#71a3ff"/>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>                        
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>            
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: This is just an educated guess

In the `Window` class, there are `Deactivated` and `Activated` events that are called whenever focus is removed or returned to the `Window` object. *If* you have similar events in your XBAP top level `Window` object, you *may* be able to utilise them. [I'm sorry, but MSDN is currently down so I can't verify if this is correct.]

If you can attach to the `Activated` event, then you could possibly refresh the UI to restore its full functionality each time the application is focused again.